# What is the best way to express the frequency of some action?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, prepositional-phrases

I want to state in an email to a colleague:

> I am going to speak with the customer and want to be as informed as
>   possible regarding **the frequency at which we have been receiving
>   checks**.

Is this the best way to construct this sentence?  I'm especially struggling with how the preposition function in this sentence (should I use of or at?).

Comment: I would reword it like so: I am going to speak with the customer and want to be as informed as possible; please provide me with their record of payments (for the past six months). This should give you the dates and amounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something happens *at* a particular frequency, so it's *at which.* It's a frequency *of* doing something. Technically, I suppose it's *frequency **of** <noun phrase>* and *frequency **at which** <verb phrase>.* A gerund functions as a noun phrase.

> The frequency at which we have been receiving checks
>   The frequency of our receiving checks

But here, you may not need it at all. *Frequency* is a technical word. If you do need that implication of precision, fine; but if all you are asking is how often something happens, just use that:

> how often we have been receiving checks

If you actually need hard data, you'll need to request that explicitly, as [Davo has commented](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/372620/what-is-the-best-way-to-express-the-frequency-of-some-action#comment872260_372620).